# Angular/NodeJS - Mongoose Pagination

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

This is more a design question than a lot of code.
I have my angular client query a mongodb collection via http and nodejs backend.
I want to paginate the result, so what I do is on the angular side, keep track of the page I'm on and the # of results I would like on each page, and I pass that on to my backend via an http call.
Then my backend has code that looks something like this:

```
schema.find({name: query, _userId: req.body._userId}).sort({ name: 'asc' }).limit(req.body.num_results).skip(req.body.page * req.body.num_results).then(response => {
```

Now I'd like to put "<" and ">" arrows on my client's html where every time left or right is clicked it traverses pages (via a new http call), but then make it so that "<" is disabled on page 0, and ">" is disabled on the last page of results. I've figured out how to disable the "<" - simply make the button go away when you're on page 0. But having trouble figuring out the best way to discover that I'm on the last page. One method could be for my backend to return the total number of results and then my front-end tracks where I am relative to the total #, but that involved another db call, move variables passed over http, more management on the front-end. Any ideas on how to implement a 'cleaner' solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make any additional api call. You can return any additional information in the form of Http header when making api call. so, in this case return **X-TOTAL-COUNT**

Comment: Thanks - how can I get response.length for the original .find before I apply all the filters (or do I have to run a separate query?)

Comment: here is the sample code
/ GET get all Products
router.get('/products', requireJWT, hasPermission, (req, res) => {
  const { page = 0, pageSize = 1000, sort = -1 } = req.query

  Product.find()
    .lean()
    .sort({ _id: sort })
    .limit(Number(pageSize))
    .skip(Number(page) * Number(pageSize))
    .then(document => {
      // Send them back as the response
      res.setHeader('X-TOTAL-COUNT', document.length);
      res.json(document)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    })
})

Comment: Thanks I tried that code out and document.length only returns the page Size since it comes after the limit. How do I grab the overall document length #?

Comment: my bad.. you should make another call such as const total=await Product.find().length;